# Как сделать рекапчу прямоугольным?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

как сделать рекапчу прямоугольным? Мне не нравится огромный квадрат который занимает большое место.

[Ссылка с проблемой](https://kropers.com/avtorizovatsya)

Comment: Блин, серьёзно? Вы просите помощи, но при этом запрещаете на сайте открывать инструменты разработчика? За такое и минус не жалко влепить, но в любом случае по правилам сайта весь код, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы, должен находиться прямо в тексте вопроса без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы (у рекапчи тестовые ключи есть, если что)

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает, можно я на него просто дам ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987)

Comment: Добавьте стиль `.rc-anchor-compact { width: 100% !important; }` И все дела.

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает ширины, возможно из-за паддинга содержащего капчу, она как бы на двух строчную разбивается. Немного погуглил, рекапчу можно изменить в таблице стилей, много ссыллок тут постить не буду, просто погугли по 'google recaptcha small'

Или вот это:

How to change the appearance and style of Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA)?

1. Open your WordPress admin dashboard.
2. Navigate to the plugin settings page.
3. Select reCAPTCHA version.
4. Find "Theme" option (only available for versions 1 and 2) and select
   the preferred style from the drop-down list.
5. Save changes and check the result.

Или так: нашел в документации https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
Тут даны параметры и стили.

Comment: Последний вариант самый правильный.

Comment: например взять по ссылке код рендерящий капчу, и добавить параметр size: compact